# Format display of notification in ios notification screen xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Is there a way to change how the text is displayed in notification area on ios >10?

For example, currently I am sending json string as the notification that contains the necessary info for the app, and in the notification area on the lock screen or pull down menu it is displaying that json string. Is there a way to customize the text that gets displayed there?

I have searched around, but the things I have found have not helped. I can handle the display of the notification when the app is in the foreground.

If it is not directly possible, would sending the notification as a silent one and then pushing a formatted notification to ios notification area be possible?

My template for reference:

```
const string templateBodyAPNS = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"$(messageParam)\", \"category\": \"test\"}}";
```

I have tried with mutable content 1, also didnt work.

The code of my extension:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using UserNotifications;
using UserNotificationsUI;

namespace NotificationContentExtension
{
    public partial class NotificationViewController : UIViewController, IUNNotificationContentExtension
    {
        protected NotificationViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            // Note: this .ctor should not contain any initialization logic.
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            // Do any required interface initialization here.
        }

        public void DidReceiveNotification(UNNotification notification)
        {
            label.Text = "Hello";
            new UIAlertView("Received", "Working", null, "Ok").Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#creating-custom-user-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a **Notification Service Extension** to your Xamarin.iOS project in order to customize the way the push notification is presented.

1.In Visual Studio go to File/new Project/Visual C#/iOS Exensions/Notification Service Extension.

2. The Notification Service must have a bundle name that has the iOS project as the prefix:

   **iOS project bundle id:  www.companyname.iosappname**

   **Extension bundle id:     www.companyname.iosappname.extensionname**
3. Need to add a reference to the iOS project that points to the extension. So right click on the iOS project, add reference and select the extension project.
4. Currently in Visual Studio after you add the Extension reference to the iOS project you will only be able to run the iOS project in Release mode, not in Debug mode. If you try in Debug mode you will get an error. To run in debug mode, remove the Extension reference first from the iOS Project.
5. You need to change the APNS format to:

   **const string templateBodyAPNS = @"{
                                       ""aps"" : {
                                               ""alert"" : ""$(messageParam)"",
                                               ""mutable-content"": 1
                                                 },
                                   }";**

   Adding "mutable-content":1 signals that a Notification Service will intercept the 
   push notification.
6. The Notification Service Extension cannot exchange data with the main iOS project. 
   In order to **share data** between the two you will need to create an **App Group** on the 
   Apple Developer website. Make sure you add the app group to both projects in their Entitlements.plist files and also on the Apple Developer Website.
7. You need to activate push notifications on  the Apple Developer Website for both your project and the Notification Service Extension and also create certificates and provisioning profiles for both.
8. Only publish the iOS Project, the Extension is automatically included.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Just a question wouldn't notification content extension be more suitable for this? Since I only need to modify how the notification is displayed?

Comment: @Lukasstoop There might be some differences actually check out this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/advanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows

Comment: So I have followed that documentation, apple's documentation and everything else I can find. But my content extension isnt being invoked. I am deploying in release mode, all the profiles are setup, and I have tried various template bodies, and nothing. @EmilRR1

Comment: @Lukasstoop Did you add a reference to the iOS project to the Extension, and also made sure it appears in references by right clicking the iOS Project?

Comment: @Lukasstoop  Also make sure you have an "APNS devemlopment certificate" (if developing) and 
 an "Apple Push Sertvices" certificate for EACH (iOS Project and Extension) and also provisioning profiles for both. When you create the certificates use the same CSR for both app development and APNS develoment, and same CSR for distribution and Apple push services respectively. Also make sure when you right click on the iOS project that the Entitlements.plist show up under  "Custom Entitlements". Also very important make sure the Deployment Target is same for both iOS project and Extension.

Comment: I have the iOS project referencing the extension project. I have the certs and profiles setup. But if I remember correctly the push notifications are signed with different certs. Also previously if I make the iOS project reference the entitlements.plist it breaks completely. Also I have to deploy the iOS project with the AD-HOC target, unless you mean iOS target which is iOS 10. @EmilRR1

Comment: @I was referring to the iOS version. Both projects should reference same target. If there is an error in the extension code, the push notification will be delivered in original format. Make sure the extension code should work as well. And I assume you already have an App ID with the extension bundle with notification enabled.

Comment: Yes I have the app id set up. At the moment, all I do on the extension is set the text of the label that is auto generated on the storyboard to hello inside the did receive notification method. I will edit my post with the code of my extension. @EmilRR1

Comment: Thank you very much @EmilRR1, after some struggle I got it to work. I ended up using a service extension and not a content extension. Thanks again.

Comment: @Lukasstoop Im happy it worked for you. I know how frustrating it can be. Anytime.